# How call a block named Poll Recent from template?

Tags: blocks, theming

I need to call the block Poll-recent from template.  I have tried this code and not work for me.  I am working in Drupal 7.

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view','poll-recent'); 
print $block['content']; ?>
```

or

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('poll', 'block_view','recent'); 
print $block['content']; ?>
```

What is my error?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In D7, you will need:

```
$block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
print render($block['content']);
```

In the case of recent poll:

```
<?php
  $block = module_invoke('poll', 'block_view', 'recent'); 
  print render($block['content']); 
?>
```

Curiously, although defined in [poll_block_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!poll!poll.module/function/poll_block_info/7) the delta is actually ignored in [poll_block_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!poll!poll.module/function/poll_block_view/7), perhaps as the poll module only provides a single block.

Answer (score 0):

@cabita: Try adding in a fourth argument 'block_delta' and using the render function to print the output, as suggested [in this detailed post on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/26502)

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: I tried with $block = module_invoke('poll', 'block', 'view', 'recent'); and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work;

```
$block = module_invoke('poll', 'block_view','recent'); 
print render($block);
```